# Is there a way to align divs as a grid with different height and width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align some div elements with pure css, but the problem is that those elements can have different heights and widths.

I've already tried to use tables and grid but I can't figure out the right way to do it.

This is the output I want when there are 8 div in the following order

```
<div style="height: 2;width:2;"></div>
<div style="height: 1;width:2;"></div>
<div style="height: 2;width:2;"></div>
<div style="height: 2;width:3;"></div>
<div style="height: 2;width:2;"></div>
<div style="height: 1;width:3;"></div>
<div style="height: 1;width:2;"></div>
<div style="height: 1;width:4;"></div>
```

I'm new here so I cant post images, but here is the link for the expected output https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzGm2.jpg . I'm wondering if that is even possible with css3.

[Edit] : I'm looking for [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) behavior but with pure css and with different width and heights, that's because I want to use this in a [IMG to HTML converter](https://gabrieldonadel.github.io/img-to-html) project

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for, but [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) might be the answer

Comment: are you looking for a [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) behaviour?

Comment: Yes, just as Masonry behaviour

Comment: I don't that is a duplicated question as that link that I refer only works with javascript or with only one dimension at time.